# Why can't I run a dart file inside a dir?

Tags: dart, package, project-structure, dart-pub

I have a simple dart project, it has file structure like:

```dart
darttest  tree
.
├── packages
│   ├── browser -> /Users/freewind/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/browser-0.5.20/lib
│   ├── meta -> /Users/freewind/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-0.5.20/lib
│   ├── start -> /Users/freewind/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/start-0.0.8/lib
│   └── unittest -> /Users/freewind/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/unittest-0.5.20/lib
├── pubspec.lock
├── pubspec.yaml
└── src
    └── server.dart
```

It uses the library [start](https://github.com/lvivski/start), and is very simple.

The **pubspec.yaml**:

```dart
name: darttest
dependencies:
  start: any
```

The **src/server.dart**:

```dart
import 'package:start/start.dart';

void main() {
  start(public: 'web', port: 3000).then((Server app) {
    app.get('/').listen((request) {
      request.response
        .header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8')
        .send('Hello, dart');
    });
  });
}
```

When I on **darttest** dir and run:

```dart
➜  darttest  dart src/server.dart
Unable to open file:
/Users/freewind/dev/workspace/darttest/src/packages/start/start.dart
'file:///Users/freewind/dev/workspace/darttest/src/server.dart': Error: line 1 pos 1: 
library handler failed
import 'package:start/start.dart';
^
```

It tries to find the `start` from `darttest/src/packages/start/start.dart`, but there is no such file, actually, the `start` in inside `darttest/packages`.

Do I have to put the `server.dart` inside the root of project? Is there any rule for this? Or how to fix this error?

Comment: Do you use the Dart Editor? You a missing the directory links to the /package/ folder. You can create them by running "Pub Install" on the pubspec.yaml file (context menu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
`pub install` was renamed to `pub get` (`pub install` is still available as an undocumented alias for `pub get`)
**EDIT**

> `pub install` solves this issue by creating additional `packages`
>   directories that link to the main `packages` directory at the root of
>   your package. It assumes your package is laid out according to the
>   [package layout guide](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html), and creates a linked `packages` directory in `bin/`,
>   `test/`, and `example/`, as well as their subdirectories

**Dart Editor**

If you are using the Dart Editor it can automaticly create a directory link to the main package folder.

You need to choose "**Pub Install**" from the **context menu** on the `pubspec.yaml` file in the Files view.

**Command Line**

If you want to create the directory from the command line you can use the [`pub install`](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pub-install.html) command. You need to run it in the directory of your `pubspec.yaml` file.

**PS:** Take a look at the [Package layout conventions](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html) for Dart packages. They recommend to use the `bin` folder for standalone Dart applications.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not using Dart Editor, instead, I use command line with Dart SDK. Do I have to create the link inside `src` manually? Can I run some pub command to do this?

Comment: The command line equivalent is `pub install`, see http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/#installing-dependencies and http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/pub-install.html

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to put the `server.dart` to `bin`, because it has lots of logic. And it's not a library, it's not proper to put it inside `lib`. I don't know where to put it now :(

Comment: If it contains a main and is not a tool, an unit test, an example or a web application it should be in bin.

Comment: It's the server-side of a restful api provider, where should I put it?

Comment: For me it has a main and should be in bin. But that is only a convention, you are free organise it like you need it.

Comment: @Freewind: Move logic that not related to `parsing cmd-line arguments` to separate file. Best place for this are directories `'lib'` (for `stubs`) and `'lib/src'` (for `implementation`). Organize this as project but not as `all-in-one-file`. This is the preffered way to programming in `Dart`.